# Redundant tag for Marketing Cloud

Tags: discussion, tag-merge

I have found several questions tagged with [salesforce-sfmc], which should have been tagged with [marketing-cloud]. Can you please merge these two? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I merged those two tags. There weren't any unique questions with `salesforce-sfmc`, so the tag is simply synonymized to `marketing-cloud` now.

Comment: Thank you, David